# Cloudbees instance sizing

Tags: cloudbees

I am preparing to configure our production Cloudbees instance, and would like some advice on app-cell sizing.  We will be using multiple instances with auto scaling enabled, but need to choose the app-cell size.  This is obviously a compromise between horizontal and vertical scaling and the best choice will be different for each app.

Our app is a shopping service written in GWT, so there is one JSP and an initial download of the application HTML, JS, CSS, and Image files.  After that, everything runs in the clients' browser with only search calls hitting the server and returning plain JSON with no serialization.  Also, we are not using sessions, and do not need any type of state on the server, so the memory footprint should be low.

Given all of this, my gut is to go with a more horizontally scaled deployment with a larger number of smaller instances.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to this question. Application design and internal processing comes in the equation and changes the result. Only load test can give you answer about the best sizing for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Statelessness implies you can scale horizontally very easily - so this opens up both ways to scale.

My suggestion is to fine which "container size" works well enough for a single instance (usually a memory restriction) and once you are happy with that, you can then scale horizontally based on usage.